# Replicating records and imputation with date differences in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

having a dataset with specific columns - CustomerCode, Customer, Transactionnumber, Transaction_date, Due_date, and payment_date. I'm trying to create a summarized table with a new column called date that follows certain rules based on conditions from other columns.

Here's what I need to achieve:

- If pay_date is not null, I want to add Due_Date to a new column called date.
- If pay_date is null, I need to calculate the months between Due_Date and Transaction_Date and add the last day of each month in the date column.
- Additionally, I want to duplicate the entire record for each month.

For instance, consider this example:

Original table:

| Transaction_Date | Due_Date | Payment_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |  |

Then the desired output table should be as below

| Month | Transaction_date | Due_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Jan-2023 | 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |
| 28-Feb-2023 | 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |
| 31-Mar-2023 | 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |
| 30-Apr-2023 | 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |
| 31-May-2023 | 1-Jan-2023 | 1-May-2023 |

I need help with the DAX code or steps to achieve this summarization in Power BI. How can I create a calculated table that follows these rules based on the conditions in the pay_date column? Any insights or guidance on the DAX functions or steps to perform this summarization would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why you want this? Is it for relationship reasons or other?

Comment: I'm trying to mimic logic of an excel report that was hardcoded, and will need this "Month" column for further calculations

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yup made it perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table1:

[image]

Create a new date table as follows:

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Create a new table as follows:

```
Table2 = 
GENERATE(
    Table1, 
    FILTER(
        DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date], Table1[Transaction_Date], EOMONTH( Table1[Due_Date],0)),
        'Date'[Date] = EOMONTH('Date'[Date],0)
    )
)
```

[image]

---

**Supplimental**

Adding on to this answer:

- With the conditional check on "pay_date".
- Doesn't need a Date table created, however if you have one already in your model, then tweak to use the same concept as above.

```
TableTR 2 = 
  var withPDate = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      FILTER(TableTR, NOT ISBLANK(TableTR[Payment_Date])),
      "Month", [Due_Date],
      "Transaction_Date", [Transaction_Date],
      "Due_Date", [Due_Date]
    )
  
  var withoutPDate = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      GENERATE(
        FILTER(TableTR, ISBLANK(TableTR[Payment_Date])),
        FILTER(
          CALENDAR(TableTR[Transaction_Date], EOMONTH( TableTR[Due_Date], 0) ),
          [Date] = EOMONTH([Date], 0)
        )
      ),
      "Month", [Date],
      "Transaction_Date", [Transaction_Date],
      "Due_Date", [Due_Date]
    )

  return UNION(withPDate, withoutPDate)
```

Comment: Davide - great solution! Hope you don't mind me adding to your answer, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Good answer Sam. If you'd added your answer separately, I could have upvoted it for you.